# Help Please! Lost my Samsung Galaxy S7 edge!

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I lost my Samsung Galaxy S7 edge in OLA Auto on March 23rd 2017 chennai (Driver detail is known and already inquired. He is pointing out the passengers who boarded next saying he is not aware of my mobile). I just put my mobile in power save mode by switching off mobile data and GPRS before getting down from auto. I was in the assumption that I placed the mobile in the bag while I had slipped it down in the auto seat. 
Since there is no internet connection, I am unable to track my mobile using findphone or ADM. 
The IMEI numbers are known. But helpless knowing how to track and get my treasure back. Please help.

One person attended my mobile saying that he is the customer who boarded the auto and when I asked for his mobile number and address to come to his home and collect and mobile, he cut the call. since then, i kept calling my number, he dint pick up and cutting the call randomly. by 10 pm night, the mobile got swtiched off and it is saying switched off till now. Please help. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

Call the police (you should have done that when the person had picked up your call, as the phone was on and the number could have been tracked).

Do you have Android Device Manager on phone? Then you can lock your phone from net, it'll be locked as soon as it goes online with any sim card, and you'll be able to see the location.

Comment: Thanks Basu. Sorry for the delayed response. Happy to share that I have got my mobile back. The OLA auto driver was the culprit. After a week, he has switched on my mobile and untried to unlock it in midnight by pressing random buttons and also has pressed the power button rapidly which has triggerd SOS message to the emergency contact number that I have set up. with that tracked the location, got to know that it is the driver location and with the help of police was able to get my mobile.

Comment: Long journey to get mobile back!! Take care from next time :-)